# what animation tool/software do you think is used for this?

Tags: animation

what animation tool/software do you think is used for this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeVmR4U-PYs

Comment: I'm kinda getting the feeling it could've been done in some mobile app... There's also the phone portrait aspect ratio used in all of those videos. The mobile space is full of applications for making simple animations whereas simple desktop animation software might be harder to find.  Not that this animation couldn't be done in just about anything... but if this is what you want to animate, you probably don't want to learn an overly complex app.

Comment: @Joonas - yeah, it does look a bit 'painting by numbers'.

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter, use something you know how to use. It has so low framerate and does not use any interpolation. You could do this with any graphics software or even cutouts on paper. Nothing fancy needed.

Just animate forward in whatever you use, save files out. Then convert the frames to a video. Lots and lots of tool out there for this stuff.

Comment: exactly, i'm looking for a very simple software not a fancy one, also able to create the effect where he extended his hand at this minute https://youtu.be/yeVmR4U-PYs?t=8

Comment: @JamesGates use whatever you use for drawing right now. Its done by drawing each frame. Then erasing excess and moving the finger portion.